# Why weren't TCP and SCTP designed to be used over UDP?

Tags: internet

As is well known, TCP and SCTP are usually used over IP directly. But I find some advantages if they were designed to be used over UDP:

- They won't need ports, maybe also checksum, since UDP provides ports and checksum.
- They will be able to be implemented in user space.
- NATs won't have to implement them. Maybe there are still some NATs out there without support for SCTP.
- Protocols like DNS will be able to do the TCP handshake faster in case the reply is too long for UDP, because a UDP packet will have already been sent in that case.

So why weren't TCP and SCTP designed to be used over UDP?

By comparing TCP with SSL, it's easy to see,

- The application which uses SSL wants a secure and reliable channel. Since TCP is reliable, it can harness TCP to save effort.
- The application which uses TCP and SCTP wants a reliable channel. Since UDP provides a channel, they can harness UDP to save effort.

I tried to think about the disadvantages of TCP and SCTP being over UDP. I only came up with that, then the server will have to distinguish when TCP or SCTP is being used. It can be solved by using another port (like 443 and 80) or using a command (like `STARTTLS`).

Answer (score 2):

There are difficulties implementing TCP over UDP, mainly :

- [TCP packets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) and [UDP packets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure) have an incompatible format.
- TCP and UDP have different protocol numbers (seen in the [IP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header)),
  meaning that TCP packets for a UDP port would not be passed to the correct
  upper-layer protocol.

Nevertheless, protocols which implements TCP algorithms on top of UDP
have been implemented for very specific needs.
This is called "Pseudo TCP", mainly used by P2P applications
because NAT traversal for TCP is more complicated than for UDP.

There are two Pseudo TCP variations:
[Libjingle](https://developers.google.com/talk/libjingle/developer_guide)
and [Libnice](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libnice/libnice/).
Libjingle is an open source library from google used initially for gtalk.
Chrome desktop also uses libjingle for reliable connections.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking why TCP and SCTP weren't **designed** to be used over UDP, not implementations like that. If TCP and SCTP were designed to be used over UDP, there wouldn't be the problems you described.

Comment: I would guess that the reason is simply that they were designed by two different teams. Wikipedia lists the developer of [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) as David P. Reed, while [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) was based on a paper by Vint Cerf and Bob Kahn. Not the first casualty of the famous [Not Invented Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here).

Comment: Remember also the relative power of the machines at the time.  A few bytes of overhead doesn't seem like much to us, but in the 70s when a 600 baud modem cost over a hundred dollars and memory was called "core" because it was made of thousands of ferrite-core coils such things were expensive. This is also why the checksum field for ethernet was originally a packet length, and the destination address comes first on the wire in all protocols (so the computer can stop listening as quickly as possible if it's not the recipient.)